# Why can't I use a space in my array program?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

If my input is a long name like "lsdhfjkhsdkjhfgkjhasd", then it is OK to print out. But if I use a space between a name like "fsdaf fdsaf dsaf ", then it does not show.

```
int main () {
    int total_hours;
    char name[100],category[140],nic[140];

    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);

    printf("NIC:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nic);

    printf("category:\n");
    scanf("%s",&category);

    printf("Total Hours:\n");
    scanf("%d",&total_hours);
    printf("%s \n  %s \n  %s \n  %d \n ",name,nic,category,total_hours);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Reread whatever `scanf` thing you read. %c is for a character. If this is C++, use a `std::string` and `std::getline` for a line.

Comment: And if it is C, then don't use `scanf()` either. Use sane and easy-to-use functions such as `fgets()`.

Comment: Now that the `printf` is added, again, %c is for a character. Passing a pointer to a character is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your question is tagged both 'c++' and 'c'. So which language do you actually use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP didn't read the documentation.

Comment: Change all "scanf("%c", &xxx)" to "scanf("%s", xxx)". %c is for reading **one** char. %s is for reading an array of char.

Comment: i am using c language ,and i tried c++ also to do it .but i need how to do in c language .

Comment: i did alrady same problem @Michael Walz

Comment: @user3077137: see the last answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use fgets, scanf ends on whitespace. and for C++ you should be using the higher level constructs. e.g. cin, cout

example

```
fgets(name, 100, stdin);
```

answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
int total_hours;
char name[100],category[140],nic[140];

printf("Name:\n");
fgets(name, 100, stdin);

printf("NIC:\n");
fgets(category, 140, stdin);

printf("category:\n");
fgets(nic, 140, stdin);

printf("Total Hours:\n");
scanf("%d", &total_hours);
printf("%s \n  %s \n  %s \n  %d \n ",name,nic,category,total_hours);
getch();
}
```

Comment: i am beginner in c language , all i can use is array and scanf printf and function,for ,do while ,and if,switch statement  that is  all i know .

Comment: check the language documentation for fgets() it can also read from files and does not end on whitespace like scanf.

Comment: also when pointing to an array you do not need to use the & operator as stated in the other answer.

Comment: yah i can see that but is there any simple  way to do it .

Comment: just replace scanf with fgets for all but total hours, fgets(arrayname, length, stdin); I added the solution above.

Comment: yahe :) ,thank you so much , now i can put space and it shows the name as i wished . thanks  @shenk

Comment: In fact, you *shouldn't* put the ampersand there because then you end up with the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

basically scanf copies input text into your array however its 
limitation is scanf stops when it encounters whitespace.
For that reason your first word will be copied successfully but remaining part will be discarded.

You can easily test with "word1_word2" "word1 word2" phrases. You will see, first one will be copied successfully but for second one only "word1" will be copied because scanf will stop when it reads first whitespace between two words.

Comment: yes that is what i am asking about if i put "-"or "+"or any other char it show the input ,but if there is a space it will not.

Comment: absolutely, because as i explained scanf stops when it reads whitespace. you can send underscored version of your input and then you can replace underscores via whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Name:\n");
scanf("%s",name);
```

You have to rewrite them as above.The name of an array is an address. So if you want to point to it, you should use `name` instead of `&name`. and you want to get an array of characters. so you have to use `"%s"` instead of `"%c"`.

Comment: i did it is the same .

Comment: Note that this will open up the possibility of buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking char array input one after another. While he gets space separated inputs it takes the spaces as a input also. Check this code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int total_hours;
    char name[100],category[140],nic[140];

    printf("Name:\n");
    gets(name);

    printf("NIC:\n");
    gets(nic);

    printf("category:\n");
    gets(category);

    printf("Total Hours:\n");
    scanf("%d",&total_hours);
    printf("%s \n  %s \n  %s \n  %d \n ",name,nic,category,total_hours);

    return 0;

}
```

N.B. when you try to take string/char array input using "scanf", there should be no "&". (e.g. scanf("%s",name); )